# Write a method that takes in an array and an object and returns an array with their corresponding values in the object

Tags: javascript

Write a method that takes in an array and an object. The method should return  a new array where elements of the original array are replaced with their corresponding values in the object.
I'm confused as to why it's not returning anything. Am I on the right track? I'm not sure if I should be do arr = result.

```
   function elementReplace(arr, obj) {
        var result = [];
        for (key in obj) {
            result.push(key[obj]);
            arr = result;
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    arr1 = ["LeBron James", "Lionel Messi", "Serena Williams"];
    obj1 = {"Serena Williams": "tennis", "LeBron James": "basketball"};
    
    elementReplace(arr1, obj1); // returns ["basketball", "Lionel Messi", "tennis"]
```

Comment: just pointing out that `key[obj]` in the for loop should probably be `obj[key]`, and that it looks like you should be iterating over `arr1` to look in `obj1` instead of just iterating over all of `obj1`. Apart from that its a decent start at solving the problem (even if its not a solution yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm confused as to why it's not returning anything.

Your function *is* returning something, it is returning an array which looks like:

```
[undefined, undefined]
```

You need to ensure that you use `console.log()` to log the returned value to the console. You're getting `undefined` because of your use of `key[obj]`. When you use a [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop, the `key` represents the *keys* in your object, meaning you need to use `obj[key]`

> Am I on the right track?

You're right in that you need a loop, however, you're looping over the wrong thing. The question asks you to create a new array where the elements from the original array are replaced with their corresponding values in the object. This means that you need to loop over the elements inside of `arr`, and treat each element as a *key* from `obj`. Using that *key* you can use `obj[key]` to get the corresponding value for that key from the object. You would also need to ensure that the key is inside of the object to see whether it holds a value or not.

Logic would be as follows:

```
FUNCTION elementReplace(arr, obj)
  result <- []
  FOR elemKey in arr DO:
     IF elemKey is a key of obj THEN:
       push obj[elemKey] to result
     ELSE:
       push elemKey to result
     END IF
  END FOR
END FUNCTION
```

> I'm not sure if I should be do arr = result.

You don't need to do `arr = result;` as this just re-assigns the local `arr` variable inside your function to the new array `result` that you're creating. This doesn't achieve much as you're not doing anything with `arr` in your current code.

Solution (try and attempt the above first before revealing):

> ```
>  function elementReplace(arr, obj) {
>
>    const result = [];
>
>    for (const elemKey of arr) { // iterate through each element in the array
>      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(elemKey)) // check if object has key
>        result.push(obj[elemKey]);
>      else
>        result.push(elemKey);
>
>    }
>
>    return result;
>  }
>
>  const arr1 = ["LeBron James", "Lionel Messi", "Serena Williams"];
>  const obj1 = {
>    "Serena Williams": "tennis",   "LeBron James":
>    "basketball"
>  };
>
>  console.log(elementReplace(arr1, obj1)); // returns ["basketball", "Lionel Messi", "tennis"]
> ```

Alternatively, you could use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and take advantage of that fact that each value in the object is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), meaning if you get a [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value from your object, it must be `undefined`, allowing you to default your values:

> `const elementReplace = (arr, obj) => arr.map(key => obj[key] || key);`